# Minimize ‖Ax−b‖ (how to write function to use with scipy.optimize.fmin() )

Tags: python, scipy, minimize, algebra

I am trying to minimize `‖Ax−b‖` through the `scipy.optimize.fmin` function. The data we use is:

```
A = np.row_stack([[1,1,2],[1,2,1],[2,1,1],[2,2,1]])

B = np.row_stack([[1],[-1],[1],[-1]])
```

x is found by `x=(AtA)^(−1)Atb`, and below is my code for this task.

```
def find_x(A,B):
    At = np.transpose(A) # Transpose A
    AtA = np.matmul(At, A) # Multiply A with At
    return np.matmul(np.matmul(np.linalg.inv(AtA),At),B)
```

The assigntment says that I should compare this result with the result of `scipy.optimize.fmin()`, and from what I have read I need a object/ function for `fmin` to solve. But I don't really get how I would write the code for that function without it containing x, which is the vector I want to find through the optimization.

I've tried to do the basic thing of defining a function like this:

```
def f(x):
    k = np.subtract(np.matmul(A, x), B)
    return np.linalg.norm(k)
```

And the run it through:

```
def fmin(x0):
    return scipy.optimize.fmin(f(x),x0)
```

where x0 is some initial guess (same shape as the result from find_x), but I only get a error message "'numpy.float64' object is not callable"

Comment: `scipy.optimize.fmin(f(x),x0)` should be `scipy.optimize.fmin(f,x0)` you want to pass a function which takes some input, not an *already evaluated function* (or as the docs say: **func callable func(x,*args)** -> **callable!** != `"'numpy.float64' object is not callable"`). The other stuff looks a bit noisy, but should be okay (although i did not test anything). (side-note: the tasks of comparing against fmin is very strange as this would be the last algorithm in the world one should use -> no use of first- or second-order information for such a naturally smooth optimization-problem)

Comment: Aah alright, thanks! I'm very new to python and haven't yet gotten used to find the information I need through the docs, but I will try and do a deeper search next time! 

But anyway, do you mean that I could "define" f inside the fmin-function? Because that's what I tried but I can't run the code because x is an unidentified variable. But hos else would I define f without x? The purpose of fmin is to find x.

And I wasn't clear in my post that this task was given to me by my professor soley as a educational task. So there's no real purpose behind comparing results

Comment: It's hard to understand what the problem is. Replacing it like in my first sentence might be enough such that it works. If not, update the question with something reproducable. Yes, x is the unknown to optimize and therefore you will never pass something evaluated on x, but some functions which are ready to get x as first parameter from scipy's fmin during it's work. Maybe you just want to google for something like *higher order functions*, maybe within *python context*.